# Открыть ссылку, заменив или добавив, код элемента

Tags: html

Нужна помощь, в HTML мало разбираюсь. Нужно открыть ссылку на сайт так, чтобы при этом в коде сайта заменился определённый элемент, ну или добавить к примеру в угол сайта свою гиперссылку. Читал про history.replaceState, так разобраться и не смог.

Пример:
<а href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Костылев,_Александр_Олегович">Button</а>
на открывшемся сайте, слово 'Карьера', должно быть заменено на другое.
P.S Иначе объяснить не получается, чего хочу добиться.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать фрейм во всю страницу и загружать страницу во врейм, там уже обрабатывать элементы скриптом. Но адрес в адресной строке будет ваш.